# o365 Calendar REST API

Tags: office365

While creating an event in the o365 Calendar REST API, is there a way to specify the Event Reminder value (1 day, 15 mintues, 1 hour, etc).   Does one exist and where is it documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, but it's something we have on our radar.